# getting react CSSTransition to work className is not changing

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

Hi I have been going throw this code for more than 4 hours now and still can't get it to work
 It cant be that hard to get a simple code like this to work 
By default sign in component should be hidden and on events it should appear
Yet It is visible no matter what this.state.SignInPage value I even tried entering it manually nothing works
So my main problems are **the in and the classNames attributes** not working

```
<CSSTransition
 in={this.state.SignInPage}
 timeout={1500}
 classNames="signinpage"           
>
  <SignInPage />
</CSSTransition>
```

By the start state by default is false yet no matter what i do it is always visible
In the console the className of the main div doesn't change either by the time

 I am using

```
"react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
"@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.0"
```

Please need your help

**Edit**
I just noticed that many of the examples I saw the conditionally rendered components was functions based not classes ,, my component is class does this make any deference ?

**Edit 2**
Problem solved by uninstalling everything then reinstalling and used the same code 
After a long day I wasn't the problem It now works

Comment: coul you share your css for signinpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an appropriate CSS style to coordinate with your component.

So, its good to have a class for multiple stages of your transitions like

- signinpage-enter
- signinpage-enter-active
- signinpage-exit
- signinpage-exit-active

**CSSTransition** internally hook with this CSS class which does all these magic

```
.signinpage-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.signinpage-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.signinpage-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}

.signinpage-exit-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

You can also refer [Working Example of React transition](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-banach-8l6eo?file=/src/Collapsible.jsx)